# What is the best way to ensure that a specific interface gets assigned to eth0 after install?

Tags: networking, system-installation, ethernet

I have a server with 2 network adapters, a 1gig and a 10gig ethernet. I blacklist the kernel module for the 10gig driver during PXE to ensure that it doesn't get picked up and assigned to eth0. The last step of the OS install removes the blacklisted kernel module from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. When Ubuntu starts up, it assigns the 10gig interface to eth0 again. I think this is happening on this particular server because the 10g ethernet has a lower PCI address than the 1gig ethernet:

```
lspci | grep -i network
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

I want to ensure that the 1gig adapter gets assigned to eth0. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet Interface Logical Names

Interface logical names are configured in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` If you would like control which interface receives a particular logical name, find the line matching the interfaces physical MAC address and modify the value of NAME=ethX to the desired logical name. Reboot the system to commit your changes.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html